# Do we have any guidelines toward weapons design?

Tags: discussion

I just saw in the review a question about a stun gun electric circuit which can deliver 20kV. Does the website has any guidance regarding potentially lethal circuits that the main point is to be a weapon? Also, are these questions under the authority of government concerning weapons export rules?

Comment: I don't think export rules are relevant. They control hardware, software to some extent (cryptography, ...), but I'm pretty sure they don't apply to simple information like what we're sharing on this site. The moral question remains, though.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402/what-is-our-policy-on-dangerous-stuff But it shows no definitive answer and is quite old.

Comment: @dim I just read it, I think there is a slight difference because the old post is more about dangerous stuff in general. I don't have problem with the exchange helping for high voltage application in a project with a car or personal energy.

Comment: Right, the post I indicate is more general. This is why I just mentioned it as relevant, but not as duplicate. By the way, I'm not sure you'll actually have more definitive answers. People will certainly give their point of view, but I'm afraid no "official" position will stand up.

Comment: @dim I agree on that, I don't think that a official answer will be adopt. Most likely if the debate goes on it will end up on it is the individual or the object that is dangerous. You can post your link and a short explanation and I will accept it for an answer.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it's time to do that. Maybe wait for people to express their opinion, and if they all seem to agree, even without SE mods making a final decision, it could be considered as the way to go.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Please don't **shout**, and keep your morals to yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry. but I wrote so, because terror activities are very sad

Comment: @dim,  I did-not mentioned to anyone that why someone downvoted this. And if anyone downvotes me on this-particular question, I would not mind at all, because this discussion is not-at-all a scientific or technical discussion, and is off-topic from electronics. I just mentioned an opinion, because terror- activities are very sad

Comment: I quit from discussing this controversial topic, and very soon (within few-days) I'll delete my comments on this particular question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No answer in almost a week... It seems nobody really knows what is the policy on this.

I think it is because there is actually no clear policy. A previous [relevant discussion](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402/what-is-our-policy-on-dangerous-stuff) here on meta also showed there were no official guidelines on this matter, although the general consensus seemed to be *"there should be no restrictions"*.

I also personally think that there should be no restrictions on questions asked, as long as answering them is legal (the only exception I know of being building [bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bomb-making_instructions_on_the_internet#Legislation)).

Moreover, I am quite confident that export rules restrictions here are irrelevant. These rules control hardware, softwares in a few cases (mainly cryptographic software), but I'm pretty sure they don't apply to simple information like what we're sharing on this site. Exporting from where anyway? The servers location? The poster's location?

So I don't see any reason to rule out these questions, and if anyone had such reasons in mind, I think he would have made a post here already. So we can certainly consider anyone is free to ask how to make his stun gun even more lethal, how to switch the high voltage for his DIY electric chair, ... (as long as the question is well-asked and not too broad).

Now, anyone is also free *not* to answer, and I certainly won't, as I don't value much these devices and their use.