# More emphasis on safety?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374800/what-resister-i-want-to-use-to-drop-voltage-for-led) post where somebody want to drive a string of LEDs from mains power.

Only one person ( Colin__s ) had a small note of 'Use a power supply'. 
Then nothing for ten hours. I just came across it and posted an answer with big DON'T but it had been up for ten hours before that. 
(And closed about five minutes after my post)

I found [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402/what-is-our-policy-on-dangerous-stuff) link about 'What is our policy on dangerous stuff?' which only says: "I don't think that we should have restrictions on electronics which are perceived to be dangerous."

But should we have a policy of pointing out, clearly and with emphasis, when things are dangerous?

Comment: Instead of being a bunch of annoying safety-nannies, let's get a supply of Darwin awards ready to hand out.

Comment: I think a few zaps of 120V makes you a better electrical engineer, I received a few when I was a kid.

Comment: @laptop 120V? Ha! Move to Europe when you're grown up!

Comment: @dim I did blow up a relay on 220V once, almost took out my eye.

Comment: I like how he said, "It _shouldn't_ kill you." LOL...

Comment: I would expect at least a bit of common sense from electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from this topic being discussed to death (pun intended) as you linked, you are also wrong. You can safely do this with mains voltage (capacitive dropper, resistive dropper, self or commercial wound transformers). The level of care needed to do it safely is a separate issue, which only merits warning someone that does not know how to do it, if you want. There doesn't need to be a site wide policy for that.