# Introduce flag for suicide attempt

Tags: feature-request, flagging

On a platform with a lot of users being professionals but open also to laymen, we are often confronted with questions clearly asking for help in things which pose a lethal risk to the questioner or possible bystanders but are also clearly not supported by a necessary level of experience at the position of the questioner.

It takes a lot of effort explaining, why this question in that form won't or can't be answered responsibly. In many cases I think it might be better closed to prevent others reading this questions which have only lengthy "don't do it, please" replies.

I think there should be a flag for dangerous ideas, because this could mark that question as what it is on first glance. Explanations could be more concise without citing half the regulatory corpus of the country of the OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is our policy on dangerous stuff?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402/what-is-our-policy-on-dangerous-stuff)

Answer (score 7):

#### No

Just use the custom close flag.

Answer (score 0):

1. Optionally comment or answer in a *short* and concise way to **explain** what **risks** are involved and precautions to take and that only experienced people should do whatever is being asked.
2. Then **close** and hope for the best (as far as I know the author is still able to see the post).

Answer (score 0):

We might create a (meta) question (or multiple) and answer(s) that covers typical question of that kind and link closed-as-offtopic answers to that post so that we don't have to spend time again and again to comment/answer these questions.